# Struts 2 - Syntax for iterating over a map with a conditional check on keys

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags

We are passing a  map from action class to the JSP. The map is defined as follows:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal[]>
```

I need to iterrate this map in the JSP where the KEY will be the title of a row and the BigDecimal array will be the column values of the key.

In the map there is a key named "Total" whose values is sum of other values.

For example:

```
Map = {
Key1 =  {1,2,3}
Key2 =  {4,3,1}
Key3 =  {2,4,5}
Total = {7,9,9}
}
```

I have to show the values of Total key in a row with a different color or style. hence I need to put a condition as follows:

```
<s:if test="check if the key is Total">
     Show in a colour1
</s:if>
<s:else>
     Show in colour2
</s:else>
```

I am not sure about how to put condition on a key value of a map. Can I try something with the Status attribute of Iterator ?

Please advise.

Regards
Saroj

Comment: I have soled the problem as follows.

Passed a LinkedHashMap from action instead of a Map and kept the Total key at last.

Then used the following code to check the last element in the iterator.

    <s:iterator value="myMap" status="myMapStatus">
           
     <s:if test="#myMapStatus.last == true">
      Display with Colour1
     </s:if>
    
     <s:else>
      Display with Colour2          
     </s:else>
    
    </s:iterator>

Thanx all for your help and time. 

Cheers

-Saroj

Answer (score -1):

See this example:

ActionClass:

```
public class AccountsAction extends ActionSupport {

    Map<String, BigDecimal[]> valuesMap;

    public Map<String, BigDecimal[]> getValuesMap() {
        return valuesMap;
    }

    public void setValuesMap(Map<String, BigDecimal[]> valuesMap) {
        this.valuesMap = valuesMap;
    }

    public String execute() {
        valuesMap = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal[]>();

        BigDecimal[] bdArray = {new BigDecimal(1),new BigDecimal(2), new BigDecimal(3)};
        valuesMap.put("Key1", bdArray);

        bdArray = new BigDecimal [] {new BigDecimal(4), new BigDecimal(5), new BigDecimal(6)};
        valuesMap.put("Key2", bdArray);

        bdArray = new BigDecimal [] {new BigDecimal(7),new BigDecimal(8), new BigDecimal(9)};
        valuesMap.put("Key3", bdArray);

        bdArray = new BigDecimal [] {new BigDecimal(10),new BigDecimal(11), new BigDecimal(12)};
        valuesMap.put("Total", bdArray);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The `success` maps to the jsp and jsp source is:

```
        <table>
            <s:iterator value="valuesMap" status="stat">
                <tr <s:if test="key == 'Total'">style="color: red;"</s:if>>
                    <s:iterator>
                        <td><s:property value="key"/></td>
                        <td><s:iterator value="value" status="stat1"><s:property/><s:if test="!#stat1.last">,</s:if></s:iterator></td>
                    </s:iterator>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </table>
```

Comment: have u tested this code.from the first look i believe that if statement will not work

Comment: @JamesJithin: i believe that the comment is not by the OP but by some other SO user :)

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, thanks for letting me know. :) You tell me if this will work or not?